# Quickly ranking rows in very large dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have a very large dataframe with over 500 rows and 100 columns involved, each row representing a person and column representing a performance metric:

```
[Person] [Metric 1] [Metric 2] ...
A          [num]      [num]
B          [num]      [num]       
C          [num]      [num]
D          [num]      [num]
...
```

What I want is as follows:

```
[Person] [Metric 1] [Ranking for 1][Metric 2][Ranking for 2] ...
A          [num]        [Rank]       [num]       [Rank]
B          [num]        [Rank]       [num]       [Rank]     
C          [num]        [Rank]       [num]       [Rank]
D          [num]        [Rank]       [num]       [Rank]
...
```

Now, I can use pandas.rank to do this for one column, but it seems really clunky when there are over 100 involved, not to mention having to move the columns around afterwards. Is there a quick way (maybe involving loops) to rank all 100+ columns at once?

Comment: 500x100 is not very large, it is very small!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pd.DataFrame.rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html):

```
out = (df
  .join(df.filter(like='Metric')
          .rank()
          .add_prefix('rank_')
        )
  .sort_index(axis=1, key=lambda x: x.str.extract(r'Metric(\d+)', expand=False).fillna(0).astype(int))
)
```

*NB. There are many ranking algorithms, check the documentation for the one you need.*

Dummy example:

```
  Person  Metric1  rank_Metric1  Metric2  rank_Metric2
0      A        1           2.0        1           2.0
1      B        3           4.0        0           1.0
2      C        0           1.0        2           3.0
3      D        2           3.0        3           4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Given this dataframe

```
   metric1  metric2  metric3
A        1        2        3
B        3        4        5
C        2        1        7
```

You can create each rank and a new column name

```
new_column_order = []

for index, column in enumerate(df.columns):
    df[f"rank {index+1}"] = df[column].rank()
    new_column_order.append(column)
    new_column_order.append(f"rank {index+1}")
df.columns = new_column_order
```

at the end of the for loop the dataframe is

```
   metric1  metric2  metric3  rank 1  rank 2  rank 3
A        1        2        3     1.0     2.0     1.0
B        3        4        5     3.0     3.0     2.0
C        2        1        7     2.0     1.0     3.0
```

and the list of columns reorganized (new_column_order)

```
['metric1', 'rank 1', 'metric2', 'rank 2', 'metric3', 'rank 3']
```

Comment: You should not be using normal language control statements, while using Pandas! That's why Pandas does exist!